# problem between getElementById vs getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, dom

I am getting a problem. When I apply a same rule using `getElementById` and `getElementsByTagName` , its perform differently

```js
function sk(){
    var samim = document.getElementById("demo");
    
    for(var x=0; x<samim.length; x++){
        samim[x].innerHTML= "new text" ;
    }
}
setTimeout(sk,1000);
```

In the above code i am not  able to get "new text". But when i write the code below I get "new tex" as usual. So where's the difference ?

```js
function sk(){
    var samim = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    
    for(var x=0; x<samim.length; x++){
        samim[x].innerHTML= "new text" ;
    }
}
setTimeout(sk,1000);
```

Comment: You forgot to share the (relevant) HTML code. Do you really have `<p id="p">`?

Comment: Elements is not Element. now you know.

Comment: `HTMLElement`s don’t have a `length` property. Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Comment: `.getElementsByTagName("p")` returns a list but `document.getElementById("p")` returns only one element which is the element with the id `"p"`

Comment: no i write <div id = "demo" in the main code . i made mistake here

Answer (score 1):

There can be two things like you are not having any div with id="p".
One other thing you can consider is, .getElementsByTagName() returns an array of objects, while .getElementById() returns an object,
So when you are doing : `samim[x].innerHTML= "new text" ;`
then it is working on array of index so it works fine.But it 'getElementById ' this cannot work like this

For more exact answer can you share your html?

Comment: should i i use  function for getElementById ??

Comment: Can you share html please?